# Emit a signal when the user changes of row with the keyboard (Key_Up and Key_Down) in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I don't know how to emit a signal when the user changes of row with the keyboard by pressing up or down arrow key in QTableWidget. And after, I will have to use this signal to make some changes to my video.

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass the class [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) by adding two signals :

```
class myTableWidget: public QTableWidget
{
  public:
    myTableWidget() {}
    ~myTableWidget() {}

  private:
   void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
   {
        if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Up)
            emit keyUpPressed();
        else if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Down)
            emit keyDownPressed();    
        else
            QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
    }

    signals :
        keyUpPressed();
        keyDownPressed();
};
```

In your class where you use the video, add two slots *(and let's say your class is named `yourClass`)* :

```
public slots :
    void onKeyUpPressed();
    void onKeyDownPressed();
```

Now you can use the signals and slots connection in your main class like this :

```
myTableWidget* table = new myTableWidget();
connect(table, SIGNAL(keyUpPressed()), this, SLOT(onKeyUpPressed()));
connect(table, SIGNAL(keyDownPressed()), this, SLOT(onKeyDownPressed()));
```

Then, in your slots, you can process your video.

```
void yourClass::onKeyUpPressed()
{
    // do something here
}

void yourClass::onKeyDownPressed()
{
    // do something else here
}
```

An alternative is to install an [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html).

**EDIT :** from your comment, your class inherits `QStyledItemDelegate` so you can just override the function [eventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#eventFilter) like this :

```
bool myTableWidget::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) 
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Up)
            emit keyUpPressed();
        else if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Down)
            emit keyDownPressed(); 
    }
    // standard event processing
    return QStyledItemDelegate::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Then, it is the same for the slots in `yourClass`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to connect to to signal `currentCellChanged` this will deal with both mouse clicks and keyboard movement and give you the indices of the newly selected cell.

Answer (score 1):

To catch a signal from key event you can inherit from `QTableWidget` and override method `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)`, for example:

**.H file:**

```
class CustomTableWidget : public QTableWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
public:
    explicit CustomTableWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CustomTableWidget();

signals:
    void upEvent(const QModelIndex &index);
    void downEvent(const QModelIndex &index);
```

**.CPP file:**

```
void CustomTableWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Up: emit upEvent(currentIndex());
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Down: emit downEvent(currentIndex());
        break;
    default: QTableWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
}
```